# how to use int identity as guid for merge publication?

Tags: sql, sql-server, merge-replication

How do I set the `nId` column (from the example table creation code below) up as `uniqueidentifier` to prevent the merge publication wizard from creating an unneeded GUID column?

I am trying to set up merge publication in SQL Server Management Studio 2019.

My published tables use `int` and `bigint` `identity` for their primary key.

Here is an example creation script for one of my tables:

```
create table MySchema.MyTable 
(
    nId bigint identity(1,1) primary key,
    cName varchar(100)
);
```

However, when I use the "new publication" wizard, I come to this step where it says it will automatically create GUID column for published tables:

[image: publication wizard warning]

I do not think I should need this extra column, as merge publication assigns `identity` ranges for each publisher/subscriber, so there should never be a reason the `nId` can't serve as the `uniqueidentifier`, but I can't seem to figure out how to set the `identity` column as also the `uniqueidentifier`.

Comment: `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` is a type. A `BIGINT` does not qualify. Per the message, merge replication works through a `ROWGUIDCOL` column, always; the fact that you're also using ranges on your identity value is immaterial, as the engine needs a column that's guaranteed to be immutable (and while a PK is seldom updated, this is still permitted). You can create that column yourself or have the wizard do it, but you can't omit it.

Comment: Thanks! Are there any performance considerations in whether I should just let the wizard add that column or if I should add it myself? Like if the wizard adds it, does it automatically cluster based on the new guid column or will it still cluster on the ```bigint``` column?

Comment: The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/replication/administration/enhance-merge-replication-performance#snapshot-considerations) cover this; it's recommended to create it in advance. Clustering on it is probably not a good idea (the identity is still better for that by virtue of being smaller and presumably being used in actual business queries); the only requirement for the row GUID column is that it has a unique index, but that needn't be clustered.